# The Network Adapter could not establish connection Oracle 12c

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have an oracle12c database setup on my windows 8 machine & I am trying to access this database through JDBC from ubuntu(Linux) machine present in local area network.
When am trying to establish connection through JDBC, getting the following exception

The network adapter could not establish connection.

I have ensured the following.
1. Disabled the firewalls between both the machines.
2. the URL is proper & I tired using both hostname as well as ip address.
3. listener is up and running on port 1521.(lsnrctl stat shows the listener is READY)

I have done extensive google search about this. Please help. 
Thanks in advance. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: What's your URL? Can your access DB via a client like sqlplus? What's the contents on tnsnames.ora and listener.ora?

Comment: String CONN_STRING = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address_list=(address= (community = tcp.world)(protocol=tcp)(port=1521)(host=134.139.127.98)))(connect_data=(SERVER=‌​DEDICATED)(service_name=pdborcl)))";

Comment: # tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\Oracle12c\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have used proper jdbc driver for that database connection.

Comment: I am using OracleDataSource for establishing the connection

String USERNAME="test";
String PASSWORD="test";
String CONN_STRING = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address_list=(address= (community = tcp.world)(protocol=tcp)(port=1521)(host=134.139.127.98)))(connect_data=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(service_name=pdborcl)))";

OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
ods.setURL(CONN_STRING);
ods.setUser(USERNAME);
ods.setPassword(PASSWORD);   

Connection conn1 = ods.getConnection();

Comment: Am using ojdbc6.jar. Can you tell me what exactly is that proper jdbc driver you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

try to telnet the computer (Windows 8)  that is running DB from client computer (Ubuntu).

Comment: telnet <host ip> 1521
Trying 134.139.127.98
conncted to 134.139.127.98
Escape character is '^]'

implies telnet is working fine